# Getting Unknown failure (Failure) Error while Installing APK in Redmi mobile

Tags: android

I am getting an Unknown failure Error while installing an apk via USB. I am using android mobile of 4.4 android version. ( Model number- HM NOTE 1S ). 
I have done following setting in Privacy setting:
 enable unknown source, 
 enable verify app .

In developer Option I enabled
 install via USB,
 Verify app over USB,
 Stay awake.

Thanks in advance please suggest me what I am missing....

Comment: How you built the apk using Andrio studio or Eclipse or xamarin? And what is the api details on the APK ?

Comment: Hi sandeep, I am also using the same HM NOTE 1S, while installing apk through USB cable it will ask a permission to install the apk or not for 5 seconds, if you not perform any action on that pop-up, it will the same issue "UNKNOWN FAILURE, error installing apk"

Comment: i think you got it, try to accept the permission then the application will be installed, i my case i am using android studio, don't know what you are using

Comment: I am using android studio, But I am not getting any popup for permission

Comment: check gradle is building correctly, maximum you need to get the pop-up to accept or deny apk instalation

Comment: gradle is building correctly because in other mobile it is installing

Comment: Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Install via USB: Uncheck your App if it's listed.
Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy: Check the Unknown Sources option.
Finally go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options: Check the Install via USB option.     sign in into our mi account to enable verify app over USB

Comment: Try revoking USB debugging authorizations and uninstall any previous app

Comment: still getting same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also geeting the same error in Mi Pad.

I solved it like this:

**1. File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment.**

**2. Instant Run -> disable "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy".**

**3. Apply -> OK**

**4. Build -> Clean Project -> Run**

It works smoothly